# Allow only Object Change Notification in App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

There is a Google App Engine application that processes [Object Change Notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification).

How to secure it properly, so it can receive notifications only and not to be exposed for anything else?

Answer (score 1):

One way to set up a system of setting apart genuine notifications from the watched resource, and of discarding other, unwanted POST messages, were by using a token when setting up the notification channel. The same token should be returned via headers in the notification message. It is then enough to simply check headers for the presence of that token. In short, genuine notification messages will have the proposed token in a specific header, so you only need to check that header to confirm that the notification is authentic.

As an example, to set up this functionality with a token called “ClientToken” you can run the gsutil notification command:

```
gsutil notification watchbucket [-i ChannelId] [-t ClientToken] ApplicationUrl gs://BucketName
```

The resulting request generated by the above command may look similar to:

```
POST /storage/v1/b/BucketName/o/watch?alt=json HTTP/1.1 
Host: www.googleapis.com 
Content-Length: 200 
User-Agent: google-api-python-client/1.0 
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: Bearer OAuthToken 

{ 
"token": "ClientToken", 
"type": "web_hook", 
"id": "ChannelId", 
"address": "ApplicationUrl" 
}
```

The above command creates a new notification channel, that can be used to send notifications when the a change happens with the watched object. A sample of such a message may look like:

```
POST /ApplicationUrlPath 
Accept: */* 
Content-Type: application/json; charset="utf-8" 
Content_Length: 0 
Host: ApplicationUrlHost 
X-Goog-Channel-Id: ChannelId 
X-Goog-Channel-Token: ClientToken 
X-Goog-Resource-Id: ResourceId 
X-Goog-Resource-State: sync 
X-Goog-Resource-Uri: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BucketName/o?alt=json
```

The structure of this message allows you easy identification of the client token included with the the help of header X-Goog-Channel-Token:

```
X-Goog-Channel-Token: ClientToken
```